# Issue Installing java on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java

so i was installing java and my pc decided to shut off before it could finish, i don't have java anymore, and now when i try to open the installer it never opens, i have tried using CCleaner to clean the registry, i have tried installing in safe mode, someone told me to check the checksum to make sure the file isn't corrupted and its not, i have tried the offline and online installers with no luck

i have been trying to solve this for a week with no luck =P was hoping you guys could help

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft's `Microsoft Fixit utility` Software to CleanUp Registry automatically.

Or, go to java.com and search

> After uninstalling Java, how do I remove its listing in the Windows
>   Uninstall/Remove Programs?

Then Download java and install